# Kubernetes env variables not working in sequelize-cli

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, sequelize.js, skaffold

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

`sequelize-cli` uses a `./config/config.js` file that contains the following:

```
module.exports = {
  username: process.env.PGUSER,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  port: process.env.PGPORT,
};
```

If you `console.log()` all of thee `process.env.<var>`, it all comes back `undefined`.

However, if go into the `index.js` where the Express app resides and `console.log` the same thing, it comes back with the expected values.

I have Kubernete running with `skaffold.yaml` and `minikube` during all of this.

Is there a way to get this working without creating a `.env` just to run these commands?

**server-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: sockpuppet/server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: PGUSER
              value: postgres
            - name: PGHOST
              value: postgres-cluster-ip-service
            - name: PGPORT
              value: '5432'
            - name: PGDATABASE
              value: postgres
            - name: PGPASSWORD
              value: ''
```

Comment: How do you run `npx sequelize-cli` command and how do you run `index.js`? How do you define environment variables? If environment variables are defined - they would have been used.

Comment: I'm just running `npx sequelize-cli` from an open terminal. The `index.js` is started with `skaffold`. I've posted how the env variables are declared in the k8s manifest.

Comment: Can you try exec into the container and check `env` to determine if this is kubernetes or the JS framework?

Comment: Doing a `kubectl exec server-deployment-656bfc8cd6-lgt8g env` lists the env variables. However just running `env` from where I am trying to run `npx sequelize-cli`. I figure what is happening is that just running `npx sequelize-cli` from the terminal is outside the context of the running k8s-skaffold stuff. I need to figure out how to run `npx sequelize-cli` within the running k8s environment. Not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't pretty, but this is the best I could figure out. Hopefully someone has a better answer...

Since this is a `deployment` that consists of three replicas, it produces three pods. Have to get the id for one first:

```
kubectl get pod
```

Once I have that I can do the following:

```
kubectl exec -it server-deployment-84cf685559-gwkvt -- npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

That works, but kind of messy.

Came across [this link](https://tobernguyen.com/execute-command-on-pod-of-deployment-single-command/) that be more efficient especially if just making an `alias`:

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o name | grep -m1 INSERT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME_HERE | cut -d'/' -f 2) INSERT_YOUR_COMMAND_HERE

kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o name | grep -m1 server-deployment | cut -d'/' -f 2) "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate"
```

Comment: You probably need to check of kubernetes init containers

Comment: Have you found any better alternative to the same problem above? If so please share the link or steps. @cjones